# returning object with .each throws Uncaught Reference error

Tags: jquery

I'm rewriting some code that works into code that's currently not working. Basically, I loop through divs to find out which one is visible and I want to continue by caching this div into a jquery object.

```
    $('#MainDiv .LPanel').each(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':visible') === true) {
            var ThePanel = $(this);
        }
    });

    if (ThePanel.width() < 700) { // bugs here
```

Why is ThePanel not accessible?? What am I missing?

Thanks for your suggestions.

PS: the code that works just returns `attr('id');` but I want the whole object!

Comment: Yep, I wrote the exact same thing, @meze, using the selector directly is much more easy...

Comment: @Cranio deleted my comment... His code will return the last visible element, ours will return the first one.

Comment: Actually, there's only one element visible at any given time.

Comment: Then `$("....:visible").last()` ...

Comment: @Cranio: thanks, that's what I'm going with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `var` in a limited scope. The correct approach is:

```
var ThePanel;
$('#MainDiv .LPanel').each(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':visible') === true) {
        ThePanel = $(this);
    }
});

if (ThePanel.width() < 700) { // bugs here
```

Why don't you do just

```
var ThePanel = $("#MainDiv .LPanel:visible");
if (ThePanel && ThePanel.width() < 700) ...
```

???

Comment: Sorry guys, was watching the Olympics :D It's && indeed, corrected

Comment: I think your answer should work but in my code it doesn't; don't know why. However, I'm going with the $("....:visible").last(); syntax and that works. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Actually, the reason it wasn't working was that in an edge case, all the divs are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `ThePanel` outside of the loop.  It goes out of scope every time the each callback completes.